# PHP: Отсортировать массив обьектов согласно массиву одного из свойств

Tags: php, массивы, объекты, foreach

Есть некий массив товаров как объектов со свойствами. Среди свойств кроме прочего имеется `->id` товара. Есть также массив с id номеров товаров согласно которому массив товаров нужно отсортировать и перебрать через foreach. Например имеем:

```
$sortedIDs = array(4,2,3,1);
foreach($this->products as $product) {
    echo '<div class="product" id="'.$product->id.'">';
    echo '<div class="title">'.$product->product_name.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="price">'.$product->product_price.'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Т.е. после сортировки на странице сначало должен быть товар с id=4, потом с id=2 и т.д.

Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
$productById = array();
foreach($this->products as $product) {
    $productById[$product->id] = $product;
}
$sortedIDs = array(4,2,3,1);
foreach($sortedIDs as $id) {
    $product = $productById[$id];
    echo '<div class="product" id="'.$product->id.'">';
    echo '<div class="title">'.$product->product_name.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="price">'.$product->product_price.'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

В любом случае понадобится ассоциативный массив, в котором ключами будут ID, а значениями - данные. Если вы получаете `$this->products` из базы, возможно можно получать нужный массив сразу при помощи API для доступа к базе данных. (например см. [`PDO::FETCH_GROUP`](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-1042))

Comment: Из базы, но это Виртумарт [код привел для примера], а в его модели product захлебнутся можно) Особенно мне как `$this->Iam > beginner && $this->Iam < guru` Потому остается сортировать массив там где он выводится

Answer (score 2):

Можно отсортировать массив товаров на месте, чтобы сохранить его структуру.
Минус - что больше перестановок (для `N=4` их всего log<sub>2</sub> 4! = 5, но при большой размерности массива их будет в log<sub>2</sub> N раз больше).

В программной реализации использованы функции `array_flip()` (которая переставляет ключи и значения в массиве с ID) и функция пользовательской сортировки `usort()`, которую при желании можно поменять на `uasort()` (если нужно сохранить исходные ключи объектов).

Текст программы:

```
$products = [
    (object)["id"=>3, "product_title"=>"Товар3", "product_price"=> "3333"], 
    (object)["id"=>1, "product_title"=>"Товар1", "product_price"=> "1111"], 
    (object)["id"=>4, "product_title"=>"Товар4", "product_price"=> "4444"], 
    (object)["id"=>2, "product_title"=>"Товар2", "product_price"=> "2222"] 
];

$sortedIDs = array(4,2,3,1);
$sorted_flip = array_flip($sortedIDs);
var_dump($sorted_flip);
usort($products, function($a, $b) use($sorted_flip){
    return $sorted_flip[$a->id] - $sorted_flip[$b->id];
});     

foreach($products as $product) {
    echo '<div class="product" id="'.$product->id.'">';
    echo '<div class="title">'.$product->product_title.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="price">'.$product->product_price.'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Результаты:

```
array (size=4)
  4 => int 0
  2 => int 1
  3 => int 2
  1 => int 3
Товар4
4444
Товар2
2222
Товар3
3333
Товар1
1111
```